# The loaded event on MainPage is getting called twice on application startup

Tags: windows-phone-7

The loaded event on my MainPage is getting called twice on application startup.

The constructor of the page is only getting once, and I am pretty sure that I am only assigning the event handler once also. What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Took me a while to work out what was going on, but it turns out the loaded event shouldn't be used on pages for initialization tasks, as it is not guaranteed to be called only once.

OnNavigatedTo should **always** be used instead. See the MSDN article below.

> Typically, you use the OnNavigatedTo method instead of creating an
>   event handler for the Loaded event. The OnNavigatedTo method is
>   preferable because it is only called once for each time the page
>   becomes active. The Silverlight framework raises the Loaded event each
>   time the element is added to the visual tree, *which potentially can
>   happen more than once when activating a page.*